# Custom EAV Category Attribute is Returning a Different Value

Tags: magento-2.2.5, eav-attributes, magento2.2.8

I have a custom EAV attribute called `thumbnail_link_text` which is a category attribute. When I try to display it either on the frontend or backend using the default accessor like this,

```
echo $category->getThumbnailLinkText();
```

it is always returning a value of `1`. I'm sure it is not a boolean because the data type of this attribute is `text`.

Also, in Magento 2's admin panel, I added a custom category field where you can enter an input value for this attribute.

I tried entering a new value on a certain category but it is also sets the value to `1` after saving.

[image]

I checked the database on the table `catalog_category_entity_text`, and the correct value is stored successfully. Meaning, the custom attribute is working when saving but not working when displaying. But, this is working before in production.

Another thing that's confusing is that the custom attribute is working perfectly in my development server but not in production server anymore. The dev server is a perfect clone of the production server. Only that the version of the dev is in 2.2.8 and the production is 2.2.5.

Am I missing something to check and test? Is it a directory or a file permission issue? A 3rd party or another custom module? Or an interceptor? If the category is being overridden somewhere, why is it that only this attribute is being affected?

Comment: try this $category->getData('thumbnail_link_text');

Comment: @RkRathod Thanks! I remember this might work too! But sadly, the result is still the same. It is still returning a string value of 1.